# Route naming needed for everything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Very often in a rails project, I have a 'content' controller that houses miscellaneous pages like the about us page and the contact us page and the intro page, etc.

I usually do something like

```
match '/content/:action', :controller => 'content'
```

in the routes.rb file, but I'm at a loss as to how to reference it inside my views.

What is the intended way to reference them? 
Is it:

```
= link_to "Help", '/dashboard/help'
```

Or do I need to create a named route for each of these things?

Comment: You can also enjoy this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need the named route, but it is the convention. You can do the following as well:

```
<%= link_to "Help", {controller: 'dashboard', action: 'help' } %></li>
```

And in the routes file it would look like:

```
match '/help', to: 'dashboard#help'
```

As long as you map it somehow, even doing `resources :dashboard` it will work. For a little extra help here's [the guide on Routing in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). You can also list all your routes using the `rake routes` command and it will list the routes like so:

```
 help        /help(.:format)                static_pages#help
     about        /about(.:format)               static_pages#about
   contact        /contact(.:format)             static_pages#contact
```

Which means, in this case, you can use help_path, about_path and contact_path.

Comment: cool thanks! so {:controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'help'} is still acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you better create named routes using

```
:as => "dashboard_help"
```

and in your routes you'll have

```
link_to "Help", :dashboard_help_path
```

Comment: This won't work with the : before the path, and in Rails 3.2 at least you don't really have to specify the as, doing match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help' for example will make the help_path already